# Defining my own None-like Python constant

Tags: python, singleton, constants

I have a situation in which I'm asked to read collections of database update instructions from a variety of sources.  All sources will contain a primary key value so that the code that applies the updates to the database can find the correct record.  The files will vary, however, in what additional columns are reported.

When I read and create my update instructions I must differentiate between an update in which a column (for instance, MiddleName) was provided but was empty (meaning no middle name and the field should be updated to NULL) and an update in which the MiddleName field was not included (meaning the update should not touch the middle name column at all).

The former situation (column provided but no value) seems appropriately represented by the ***None*** value.  For the second situation, however, I'd like to have a ***NotInFile*** "value" that I can use similar to the way I use None.

Is the correct way to implement this as follows?

```
NotInFile = 1

class PersonUpdate(object):

     def __init__(self):

         self.PersonID = None
         self.FirstName = NotInFile
         self.MiddleName = NotInFile
```

and then in another module

```
import othermod
upd = othermod.PersonUpdate()
if upd.MiddleName is othermod.NotInFile:
    print 'Hey, middle name was not supplied'
```

Comment: why don't you use `False` as a 'column provided but no value'? Or what about `Infinity`, it's another very special value .) Or you can inherit `Exception` class with some custom one: `NotProvided(Exception)`

Comment: Because False is a valid value for some of the columns.  Infinity doesn't seem to make any sense for this purpose.  I was considering using NotImplemented which is an available constant, but it has it's own meaning.

Comment: Inifinity doesn't make sense, I agree. But there's no chance its value can be misinterpreted .)

Comment: Interesting PEP to this topic: [PEP 661 -- Sentinel Values](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0661/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly wrong with your implementation.  however, `1` isn't necessarily the best sentinel value as it is a cached constant in Cpython.  (e.g. `-1+2 is 1` will return `True`).  In these cases, I might consider using a sentinel object instance:

```
NotInFile = object()
```

python also provides a few other named constants which you could use if it seems appropriate:  `NotImplemented` and `Ellipsis` come to mind immediately.  (Note that I'm not recommending you use these constants ... I'm just providing more options).

Comment: I saw the NotImplemented, which "sounds" close to what I'm doing but discarded the idea since it has it's own meaning.  Thanks for the info about having to use an object, however, I was not aware of the caching issue.

Answer (score 8):

No, using the integer one is a bad idea. It might work out in this case if `MiddleName` is always a string or `None`, but in general the implementation is free to intern integers, strings, tuples and other immutable values as it pleases. CPython does it for small integers and constants of the aforementioned types. PyPy defines `is` by value for integers and a few other types. So if `MiddleName` is 1, you're bound to see your code consider it not supplied.

Use an `object` instead, each new object has a distinct identity:

```
NotInFile = object()
```

Alternatively, for better debugging output, define your own class:

```
class NotInFileType(object):
    # __slots__ = () if you want to save a few bytes
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'NotInFile'

NotInFile = NotInFileType()
del NotInFileType # look ma, no singleton
```

If you're paranoid, you could make it a proper singleton (ugly). If you need several such instances, you could rename the class into `Sentiel` or something, make the representation an instance variable and use multiple instances.

Answer (score 6):

If you want type-checking, this idiom is now [blessed by PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#support-for-singleton-types-in-unions) and [supported by mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/7000):

```py
from enum import Enum

class NotInFileType(Enum):
    _token = 0

NotInFile = NotInFileType._token
```

If you are using mypy 0.740 or earlier, you need to workaround [this bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7279) by using typing.Final:

```py
from typing import Final

NotInFile: Final = NotInFileType._token
```

If you are using Python 3.7 or earlier, you can use `typing_extensions.Final` from pip package `typing_extensions` instead of `typing.Final`