# How to create a return flag object

Tags: python, object, flags

Currently [a set of functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) returns `success=True` or `False`.

We've discovered this isn't good enough, though, since `False` can convey both "valid result" or "invalid result", and we want behavior to differ in each case.

[So I think they should be changed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7819#issuecomment-331761473) to instead return `{True, False, InvalidResult}`, where `bool(InvalidResult)` is false for backward compatibility, but can be tested for using `if is InvalidResult`.

I'm not sure what the terminology is, but I'm imagining something like the [built-in `NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) that's returned by comparison functions. This is called a "special value" in the docs and is of type `NotImplementedType`.

How to create such an object and what methods/attributes should it have?  I should create my own type like `NotImplementedType` also, or is there an existing type that conveys this "flag" concept?  It's a similar kind of object to `True`, `False`, `None`, `NotImplemented`, etc.

Comment: Sounds like a "tribool"... Is `None` also a valid value or could that be used to mean no result?

Comment: cant you just use None? bool(None) == False

Comment: @georgexsh Yes, but it was thought that InvalidResult is clearer

Comment: @georgexsh Added a link https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7819#issuecomment-331761473

Comment: @endolith okay... so `InvalidResult = None` - and you're done? :p

Comment: @endolith You could have the invalid result raise an exception. Or a (success, valid) tuple.

Comment: @JonClements No, that doesn't work. Printing the return value would be empty, etc.

Comment: @endolith then you'd need to create your own singleton with desired behaviour or special case `if result is InvalidResult` (print something else...)

Comment: @JonClements Yes, that sounds right.  So it's called a "singleton"?  How do you create one?

Comment: @endolith seek and ye' will find... plenty of examples around the place by using singleton in conjuction with Python and "how do I make"... :)

Comment: It seems that raising an exception and handling that may be the more straightforward way of dealing with the invalid input, even if you just pass on the exception

Comment: @StuartBuckingham Well the function returns a dictionary of "here's what I tried and this is how it went", of which `success={True, False}` is just one component, so I don't think halting everything and raising an exception is the way to do it.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, [Tribool](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/tribool/) sounds like the same concept

Comment: (Normally I'd just have it return a string, but `bool('a string')` is True)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17424777/125507

Comment: Interesting PEP to this topic: [PEP 661 -- Sentinel Values](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0661/)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `None` or `0` as the `InvalidResult` value, e.g. in `my_mod`, define `InvalidResult = None`, then elsewhere you can test `if result is my_mod.InvalidResult`. See here for some more info on the "truthfulness" of None: [False or None vs. None or False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914667/false-or-none-vs-none-or-false)

Or you could define an object with suitable methods for Boolean conversion; hopefully others will chime in with those details.

Note that whichever way you go, you'll have to be careful if you have multipart Boolean expressions: `InvalidResult and False` will give `InvalidResult`
but `False and InvalidResult` will give `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is called a "[sentinel](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2008/12/the-magic-sentinel.html)" and is a simple as this:

```
class InvalidResultType(object):
    """
    Indicates that minimization has failed and result is invalid (such as a
    boundary or constraint violation)
    """
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'InvalidResult'
    def __bool__(self):
        return False
    def __reduce__(self):
        return 'InvalidResult'

InvalidResult = InvalidResultType()


success = InvalidResult

assert success == InvalidResult
assert success is InvalidResult
assert not bool(InvalidResult)
assert InvalidResult != True
assert InvalidResult != False  # Not sure about this yet
assert InvalidResult != None
```

*Now* of course I find the similar questions:

[Defining my own None-like Python constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277929/125507)

and the `__reduce__` might be overkill; I'm not sure if pickling or copying will ever matter

[How to create a second None in Python? Making a singleton object where the id is always the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048643/how-to-create-a-second-none-in-python-making-a-singleton-object-where-the-id-is#comment69308959_41048786)